# Echo in antunit test is not displayed

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant project in which I added on antunit test. This is the target to execute the tests.

```
<target name="test-build" depends="init-build">
    <au:antunit>
        <fileset file="test.xml"/>
        <au:plainlistener/>
        <au:xmllistener todir="${reports.antunit.dir}"/>
    </au:antunit>
</target>
```

test.xml looks like this

```
<project xmlns:au="antlib:org.apache.ant.antunit">
    <include file="build.xml" as="main"/>

    <target name="tearDown" depends="main.clean"/>

    <target name="test-project-name">
        <echo>project name is ${ant.project.name}</echo>
        <au:assertTrue>
            <equals arg1="${ant.project.name}" arg2="gradle-to-ant"/>
        </au:assertTrue>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run `ant test-build` the echo statement is not printed to the console or to the report.

```
test-build:
[au:antunit] Build File: /etc/user/john/projects/gradle-to-ant/test.xml
[au:antunit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.033 sec
[au:antunit] Target: test-project-name took 0.012 sec

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

I have seen echo used in other projects like [props](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant-antlibs-props.git;a=blob;f=src/tests/antunit/stringops-test.xml;h=8b94f68e22b7c1ccea2bbaa64e963f1ab324550e;hb=HEAD). How can I get echo to work in antunit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your `echo` task is captured so you could use assertions on it (i.e. `assertLogContains`). In props it looks as if the `echo`s are there for the case when you run the targets manually outside of antunit.

If you want to see `echo`'s output you need to add the `logforwarder` testlistener to your `antunit` task, i.e.

```
<au:antunit>
    <fileset file="test.xml"/>
    <au:plainlistener/>
    <au:xmllistener todir="${reports.antunit.dir}"/>
    <au:logforwarder/>
</au:antunit>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to try this yet but I'm sure it will work. I also discovered the antlib.xml which shows all of the assert macros. This is helpful for someone trying to learn antunit. Also thanks for being involved in the development of antunit!

Comment: You're welcome. If you download the AntUnit distribution from Apache (or one of its mirrors) it also contains a manual. For some reason we still expect this to be the default distribution point so never bothered to put the manual online.

Comment: Oh that would be nice. Im using ivy to install antunit. This is the project. github.com/moaxcp/gradle-to-ant

Comment: as the manual basically contains static HTML you can find it in https://github.com/apache/ant-antlibs-antunit/tree/master/docs

Comment: Thanks. This was a big help. It would be nice to have this published in gh-pages.